# ASP.NET Core: AddEnvironmentVariables doesn't load variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I have an `asp.net core` application (`.NET Core 2.1`). There is a code in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class:

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables("MyApp:")
    .Build();
```

Also I set **system** environment variable `MyApp:DumpFolder` to override `DumpFolder` setting in `appsettings.json`. And here I faced with strange behavior:

1. If I run the application from `visual studio` with **F5** - it can't see my system environment variable
2. If I build and run it from `bin/Debug` folder with `dotnet MyApp.dll` - it loads variables properly.

I inspected `asp.net core` and see it uses `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` method which by default (without specified `EnvironmentVariableTarget`) retreives variables from current process. I don't understand why variables aren't loaded when I run the application from `visual studio`?

Comment: Where did you declare your environment variables?

Comment: @Simonare System Properties->Environment Variables->System variables

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Restart your Visual Studio.

You probably just declared your Environment Variables hence Visual Studio does not see them.

Comment: Worked for me ! But is there also a way without having to restart VS.

Comment: I dont think so

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a bit late, but my issue was that I hadn't installed the Nuget Package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running Docker Orchestrator with Docker Compose in Visual Studio 2019. I changed my environment variables to all uppercase and they were recognized by dotnet core.

It worked with lowercase in Docker and Docker Compose outside of Visual Studio, but in Visual Studio I had to upper case my environment variables.